# get a particular item from vector based on string

Tags: c++, vector

I have a generic structure which holds a bunch of data types. For instance,

```
struct student
{
  char* name;
  char* id;
  double avg_score;
};
```

Now, I have a vector of students.

```
std::vector<student> cls;
```

How can I get a particular student, if I have char* id? Or is there any another recommended way? May be maintaining a hash of student ID and student structure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something's wrong when your variable name lights up with the same color as language's keywords.

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::find_if

```
const char* idToFind = "sdfsd";
std::vector<student> cls;
...
auto iter = std::find_if(cls.begin(), cls.end(), [=](student& s) {return strcmp(s.id, idToFind) == 0;});
student& s = *iter; 
int index = std::distance(cls.begin(), iter);
```

On aside: you cannot use "class" as variable name, and I would recommend using std::string instead of char*.

Comment: You fell into the ancient `strcmp` trap and forgot `== 0` .

Comment: thanks! i might want to stop at this place.  student& s = *iter;

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
int getStudentIndex(std::vector<student> students, char* id) {

    const int sz = students.size();
    for (int i=0; i<sz; i++)
        if (strcmp(students[i].id, id) == 0)
            return i;

    return -1; // not found
}
```

but I suspect you might need [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: This is something I might want, perhaps not the index, but the student structure it self. I can fine tune this. Thanks!

Comment: @RCBrand consider using std::string instead of char*, and read about std::map, you could have std::map<std::string,student> and get(id) students in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

A `std::map` would have been good

```
struct student {
    std::string name;
    double      avg_score;
};

std::map<string, student> m;
```

Then, to find an `id`

```
student found;
map<string, student>::iterator it = m.find(id);
if (it != m.end())
    found = it->second;
```